# MDX Scope overwriting value

Tags: scope, ssas, mdx

I am trying to overwrite the value of the member [Balance to Total] in two attributes using SCOPE. However, when I view the results in Excel they both have a value of 4. Why aren't they showing different values?

```
SCOPE ([Measures].allmembers);                   
        [Group].[Attribute1].&[Balance to Total] = 2;
        [Group].[Attribute2].&[Balance to Total] = 4;
END SCOPE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the FREEZE function solves my problem.